# Forced DCM for Buck-Boost converter

Tags: low-power, buck-boost, dcm-ccm

For a SiC MOSFET-based boost converter which operates in synchronous boost converter mode, under low load condition (less than 10% of load) i.e. when the load is less than 500 W for a 5 kW converter, How do you force the converter to operate in DCM to save magnetics losses?

L= 600 uH
Delta IL = 6 A
Vo = 400 V
Vin = 100 V
Po= 5 kW

Propose the method (a simple description, what steps to take) it has nothing to do with control and this question is not about synchronous switching. Question is: How can you force the converter into DCM in low power when using MOSFETs?